VSCode python enviroment manager does nothing when I try to set venv as active workspace interpreter
I am trying to setup a virtual environment in VSCode using the 'Python Environment Manager' extension. I can create a virtual environment based on my installed version of python and I can add packages to it but when I press the small star button to 'set as active workspace interpreter' nothing happens at all.

And if I try to press the button to the left to 'open in terminal' the following error appears:

I have tried to reinstall python environment manager, VSCode and python but the problem remains.

have you read the error message and viewed the linked web page, there you find commands to use to allow scripts to run in a PS, or use a cmd.exe shell

I read through it but unfortunately my workplace limits admin permissions and I can't request someone with permission to change the execution policy from the default unless I know that it's the cause of the issue, but I couldnt find anything online that suggested that python enivronment manager required a different execution policy.

you have to run the activate script, or type the commands from the script by hand, or switch to use a Command Prompt shell, no activation needed

Go to Command Palette [short key Ctrl+Shift+P], type "Python: Select Interpreter," and provide a path to your venv. If it does not work you can also try to activate the venv manually by typing .\venv\Scripts\activate in your integrated terminal.
For more details, you can refer to this document

Thank you very much, that worked! I will keep the question open in case anyone knows what is causing the issue with the environment manger.
